# 2 body problem question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, equilibrium

I am taking a classical mechanics course and i am struggling to determine the equilinrium points for this potential $$Q= -(k/r) + ar + (L^2/mr^2).$$ The problem is that i have to solve a cubic equation upon derivating the potential and putting it equal to zero. Also i should know the contribution of the potential to the system. So how can i know the equilbrium points? Maybe by eliminating the linear term from the potential?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways of solving the equation, in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) link you will find a recipe for the solution

$$
r_{\rm eq} = \frac{k m}{\sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{a^3 m^4 \left(27 a l^4-k^3 m^2\right)}+27 a^2
   l^2 m^2}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{a^3 m^4 \left(27 a l^4-k^3 m^2\right)}+9
   a^2 l^2 m^2}}{3^{2/3} a m}
$$